# How to create partition on hive table on date field (MM/dd/yyyy)

Tags: hive, partitioning

I have a table on which one column have date column with date format "MM/dd/yyyy"
Now, I want to create partition on the same column for every weak of the year.

As per my understanding the partition column should be there in data.

Comment: No, the partition column is actually **metadata** -- it is used to name a sub-directory that contains all data files for that partition *(or all sub-directories for nested sub-partitions).* And you'd better not put slashes in that value, for obvious reasons...

Comment: If you feed your table using "static partitioning", the partition key is defined in the INSERT clause. With "dynamic partitioning", you add the partition key(s) at the *end* of the SELECT, after the real columns, but that's a syntax trick.